# Sharepoint Branding: Sharepoint-specific attributes for Page Layouts and MPs

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I'm having trouble locating a url/document or a book, that describes extensively all the tags and attributes we can use within Page Layouts and Master Pages (**Sharepoint 2010**) in order to change the way that HTML is rendered. For example: I know there's an attribute that changes the out of the box left navigation from Tables to Unordered lists.

I'm doing front-end development and I'd like to get as much control of my html (and css of course) as possible.

One other thing is for example removing tables from web part zones and web parts. Again, are there attributes that do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For removing tables around web part zones and web parts, you will need to use a control adapter for the web part zone class. There is one available. Search for AKS_WebPartZone_Adapter

we used this with modifications for our MOSS 2007 site. We had to make additional changes to support SP 2010/

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps not the right forum for this question, but from your questions I would guess you're just getting started with SharePoint branding. I would recommend you start with a book like Microsoft SharePoint Designer Unleashed by Kathy Hughes - it provides a good overview of the kinds of things you can do to brand a site.  Even though it's written for SharePoint designer, you can definitely do branding from Visual Studio as well.

To get started, check out the content query web part - we created our own customized "quick links" view using this web part.

Comment: No, I've actually done Look and Feel customization for Sharepoint 2007 for almost two years, but I was mostly dealing with web parts, css, etc.. I didn't work with the language available in the Page Layouts and master pages per se..